# Jquery: slideup and down

Tags: jquery

How to make it sideup and side down

when i use this it sides down then up??

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $("p").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: It does up and down with only one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version - jQuery methods always return the jQuery object, which allows you to string an animation together like this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
   $("p").slideUp("slow").slideDown("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $("p").slideUp("slow", function() {
     $("p").slideDown("slow");});
});
```

Alternatively, you could create a custom animation.